# Spark 3.0.1 Dataframe Operations Work but Spark SQL does not

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I built a Raspberry Pi 6 node cluster running Hadoop (HDFS) and Spark.  I originally had Spark 2.4.3 and Hadoop 3.2.1 and Scala 2.11 working like a charm.  However, I recently upgraded Spark to 3.0.1 and Scala to 2.12, I left Hadoop alone.

When I run dataframe operations it works like a charm; however, when I try to run Spark SQL command they end up erroring out. e.g spark.sql("s e l ec t count(*) from mytable").  The data set I am using is trivially small (a few kb) but yet the Spark SQL errors out.  If I do operations using the dataframe api syntax it works like a charm.

I've attached the stderror (Link to text file in Google Drive) for one such spark sql error.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

[> 3.0.1 stderr log page for app-20201030212527-0001/2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YE5uBcZYnSnRYe8P54Wv29W0JSvWECEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There seems to be a network issue between executors and "dietpi5:32929". I'm surprised to hear that DataFrame API works fine but SQL does not. They are (almost) interchangable.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski , I put a little script together to show what I am talking about.  You can see that dataframe operations work yet sql does not:     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_NYm1BIdtxTUnW1PD6yS-16uqt5RzrNn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in sql you do `count(*)`, in dataframe api `show`, thats not the same... `show()` does anly scan a subset of the data

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, thanks for catching that.  I went ahead and added in a df.count() and the same error happens. See cell 10:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/11vniEw71WfngPqKCI9ItyITmuGcVGLD5/view?usp=sharing